# Correct dateFormat for String ending .629Z

Tags: ios, swift, date-format

I am getting this date string from a API "2017-11-25T20:41:00.629Z"

I am trying to convert it into Date type, but I  can't find the -> .629Z representation online

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

apparently this is not working and I get nil when I am converting the String into Date. I tried different things but .... !

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify milliseconds using `SSS` for your date format with 3 digit milliseconds precision.

```
let dateString = "2017-11-25T20:41:00.629Z"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
df.date(from: dateString) // "Nov 25, 2017 at 8:41 PM"
```

Comment: Why putting `Z` into quotes? That's just strange

Comment: This is wrong !!! Z means UTC time. If you scape the Z the date string will be interpreted as local time.

Comment: Besides that for fixed formats you need to set the DateFormatter locale to "en_US_POSIX" otherwise it might fail if the device locale setting uses 12h time format

Comment: **If you're working with fixed-format dates, first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX, a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. en_US_POSIX is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, en_US will change to reflect the new behavior, but en_US_POSIX will not), and between platforms (works the same on iPhone OS as it does on OS X, and as it does on other platforms)**

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the input, updated my answer

Comment: The result shouldn’t be 8pm unless you are located at 0 seconds from gmt

Comment: @LeoDabus I am actually in the GMT time zone.

Comment: Can you provide a link that someone can find all the information that you mentioning above ?

Answer (score 0):

Just found it after aaaa loooot of time

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSSz"

Thanks

Comment: There is no need to put `.` into quotes.

Comment: `z` lowercase is this case is wrong. It should be `Z`. check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkYVY.png